# I need a strategy for a t-sql procedure to extract numeric values from a heap table with requirements that shift between columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to calculate the number of credits achieved by subject category and student.  each subject category can but does not have to have up to 2 other subcategories that it can be applied too if all of the credits are not used in the primary category...

The table structure I am reading from is as follows:

```
SIS_NUMBER nvarchar(20),
STUDENT_GU uniqueidentifier,
CREDIT_COMPLETED float,
SUBJECT_AREA_1 nvarchar(600),
SUBJECT_AREA_2 nvarchar(600),
SUBJECT_AREA_3 nvarchar(600)
```

There are no primary keys in this table.  The only uniqueness is `(SIS_NUMBER, SUBJECT_AREA_1, SUBJECT_AREA_2, SUBJECT_AREA_3)` but part of the uniqueness is that `SUBJECT_AREA_2` and `SUBJECT_AREA_3` may be null.

For example here is an extract of some of the data:

```
(SIS_NUMBER, STUDENT_GU, CREDIT_COMPLETED, SUBJECT_AREA_1, SUBJECT_AREA_2, SUBJECT_AREA_3) VALUES
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 6.500, N'English', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 8.000, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 6.000, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 7.500, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 5.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 2.000, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140349', 'a6869c49-46f0-4972-93c8-cf5030d6dfd1', 3.500, N'World History & Geography', N'U.S./Az History & Geography', N'Electives'), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 0.500, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 3.500, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 2.000, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 3.500, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 0.500, N'Keyboarding/Technology', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 4.000, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 3.000, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 0.500, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 0.500, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 1.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140363', 'e904f19d-ea3b-4c24-add7-39089c8e00fd', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 0.500, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 1.500, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 3.000, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 3.500, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 1.500, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 3.500, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 0.500, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 1.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140442', 'd9b01714-ed04-4a3f-abb4-0209e686e75e', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 0.500, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 9.500, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 3.500, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 0.500, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 0.500, N'Keyboarding/Technology', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 4.000, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 1.000, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 0.500, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 1.000, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 2.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'140760', '9b29e35b-c53e-44d4-a8a5-a97b032563fe', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 0.500, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 4.000, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 4.500, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 5.500, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 5.000, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 3.000, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 1.000, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 1.000, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 1.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 1.000, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142035', 'a020cf02-ab5d-462d-9304-4be66bd19d55', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 1.000, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 5.000, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 4.000, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 1.500, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 3.000, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 3.000, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 0.500, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 2.000, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 1.000, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142047', '3eef24df-21fe-461f-bfb4-762dade65d6a', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 0.500, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 6.000, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 4.000, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 1.000, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 6.000, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 3.000, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 0.500, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 1.000, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 2.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142057', 'e7c791f3-ddaa-4a0d-829f-b6db15a6d52e', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 1.000, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 4.500, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 1.000, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 2.000, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 3.500, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 3.000, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 0.500, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 1.000, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 0.500, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142064', 'ed8aa03f-a91c-40bc-bad7-781ce16fcd45', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 0.500, N'Economics', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 3.000, N'Electives', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 4.000, N'English', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 3.000, N'Fine Arts/CTE', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 4.500, N'Mathematics', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 2.500, N'Science', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 0.500, N'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 0.500, N'U.S./Az History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 1.000, N'Wellness or R.O.T.C.', N'Electives', NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), 
(N'142152', '99e1e553-5e1b-4633-83c0-4d90d7fd1fae', 0.500, N'World History & Geography', N'Electives', NULL)
```

Every student needs to have the following credits to graduate:

- English 4.0
- Mathematics 4.0
- Science 3.0
- World History & Geography 1.0
- U.S./State History & Geography 0.5
- U.S./State Government 0.5
- Economics 0.5
- Wellness or R.O.T.C. 1.0
- Fine Arts/CTE 1.0
- Electives 6.0

For instance if the student has 2 credits and `SUBJECT_AREA_1` is "Wellness or R.O.T.C.", they will have 1.0 credit applied to "Wellness or R.O.T.C.".  If the `SUBJECT_AREA_2` field is set to "Electives" the other credit should be applied to  the "Electives" category.  Same process for `SUBJECT_AREA_3`.  Once credit is applied to a subject it should be removed from consideration for other subjects.  Subjects are weighted by the order of the above list.  Therefore English gets to fill all of it credits before Mathematics is considered and so on. Any credits that are not used after parsing all categories listed in the row will be considered unnecessary and will be left unused.

I need to flatten these records to this format:

```
SIS_NUMBER nvarchar(20),
  STUDENT_GU uniqueidentifier,
  ENGLISH_CREDITS float,
  ENGLISH_CREDITS_OUT float,
  MATHMATICS_CREDITS float,
  MATHMATICS_CREDITS_OUT float,
  SCIENCE_CREDITS float,
  SCIENCE_CREDITS_OUT float,
  WORLD_HISTORY_CREDITS float,
  WORLD_HISTORY_CREDITS_OUT float,
  US_AZ_HISTORY_CREDITS float,
  US_AZ_HISTORY_CREDITS_OUT float,
  US_AZ_GOVERNMENT_CREDITS float,
  US_AZ_GOVERNMENT_CREDITS_OUT float,
  ECONOMICS_CREDITS float,
  ECONOMICS_CREDITS_OUT float,
  WELL_ROTC_CREDITS float,
  WELL_ROTC_CREDITS_OUT float,
  FINE_ARTS_CTE_CREDITS float,
  FINE_ARTS_CTE_CREDITS_OUT float,
  ELECTIVES_CREDITS float,
  ELECTIVES_CREDITS_OUT float,
CONSTRAINT pk_credachvd PRIMARY KEY (SIS_NUMBER)
```

Where the `[Subject]_CREDITS` fields are the required number of credits and the `[Subject]_CREDITS_OUT` fields are current number of credits that each student has.

I need to process this for 100,000+ students during an batch run so I don't need instantanious response but I need to clear the process as soon as possible to make way for other batch process.

I'm looking for a strategy to get this done as efficiently as possible.  What steps would you take to divide and conquer this type of procedure?

Expected output is as follows:
(N'131237', '300712e5-dce6-428b-9978-0b45f078bf14', 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, NULL, 0.5, NULL, 1, 1, 1, NULL, 6, 3.5)

After the student SIS_NUMBER and the STUDENT_GU there will be 10 number pairs.  The first number of the pair is the required number of credits listed above.  The second number is the calculated number of credits the student currently has from the data table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're expecting as an answer, but at least there's quite a lot of issues with your data. You mentioned something that case where 'Electives' is the second field it should be handled differently:

> 'Mathematics', 'Electives', NULL),  vs "Mathematics 4.0"

But then you also have rows that are otherwise duplicates:

> 'World History & Geography', NULL, NULL), **and** 'World History &
> Geography', 'Electives', NULL)
>
> but the requirements have only one: World History & Geography 1.0

Also, it looks like your data needs also some kind of parsing since there's:

> 'U.S./Az Government', NULL, NULL),
>
> and the requirement is U.S./State Government 0.5

There's no information where the requirements are stored (in your code, a table, somewhere else?), or what your actual problem even is. Handling 100 000 rows shouldn’t take a long time no matter how you make it, even with a cursor -- which might be the easiest way since it feels like you have a lot of different rules and steps that can't be made that simply in a single fetch, and that might be the easiest code to maintain in the future.

You mention in the subject that the problem is with heap table. Why is this a heap? Usually that's only needed for maximum insert performance, but student grades doesn't sound like that. I would assume one student doesn't get that many grades per year even.